# Python string matching in if else condition

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently trying to find line based on the same pattern. If the line match the pattern, i want to print the line in output file.

Here is one the example of the line in "in.txt":

```
in_file [0:2] declk
out_file [0:1] subclk
```

The script that i currently have with the help of @gilch:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
with open("in.txt", "r+") as f:
    with open("out.txt, "w+") as fo:
    for line in f:   
        if "\S*\s*[\d:\d]\s*\S*" in line:
            fo.write(line) #need to fix this line
```

But then, is it possible to make the output like below:
e.g
Output in "out.txt":

```
in_file [0] declk
in_file [1] declk
in_file [2] declk
out_file [0] subclk
out_file [1] subclk
```

Comment: The fact that you're not getting any output means none of the lines contain `S*\s*[\d:\d]\s*\S*`. Your example line certainly does not.

Comment: Is there any way can i get it to match?

Comment: missed a quote there

Comment: For RegEx work I recommend using an online regex tester with your Regular Expression and samples to rule out problems in the RegEx itself. Just a "by the way"

Comment: @Bernhard thanks for the suggestion, the tester really help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to import the `re` module to use regex.

```
import re
with open("out.txt", "w+") as fo:
    for line in f:   
        if re.match(r"\S*\s*\[-?\d*:?-?\d*\]\s*\S*", line):
            fo.write(line)
```

Also, indentation is part of Python's syntax. The colon isn't enough.

This also assumes that `f` is already some iterable containing your lines. (The above code never assigns to it.)

Comment: Escape the square brackets

Comment: @OlivierMelançon yep, fixed.

Comment: @Inder see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star  and [regex syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=repetitions#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: Hi @gilch, i tried and nothing happen as the pattern does not match and returning none, then i tried using online regex tester, and the pattern does not match at all with my string.

Comment: @mmaz try this version. But I can only guess about which lines you're trying to match. More examples in your question would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @gilch, i tried the new version and its working. Thanks, its just that i can print the line for now, but not as what my expected output should be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
with open("out.txt", "w+") as fo:
    for line in f:   
        if re.match(r"\w+\s\[\d\:\d\]\s\w+",line):
            fo.write(line)
```